# Удаление Nan значений

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Есть датасет с большим количеством NaN значений:

```
shape (12988, 45)
vydacha_dt                        0
activation_dt                     0
pro0                              0
pro1                              0
pro2                              0
chastotta                         0
tran_type_month0                  0
tran_type_month1                  0
tran_type_month2                  0
FREE_LIMIT0                       2
FREE_LIMIT1                       2
FREE_LIMIT2                       2
limit                             0
login_0                         116
login_1                         585
login_2                        1062
withdraw0                         0
withdraw1                         0
withdraw2                         0
cred_tran_nopartnershare0      6923
cred_tran_nopartnershare1      4853
cred_tran_nopartnershare2      4589
cl_age                            0
GENDER_ID                         1
tran_prod                       315
tran_remont                     315
tran_inet                       315
CRED_TRAN_TOTAL                   0
CREDIT_TRAN_AMT_last_month     3327
CL_CHILDREN_NO                    1
City_Population_category        890
cl_income                         0
count_tran2                       0
counttran1                        0
count_tran0                       0
tran_amt2                         0
tran_amt1                         0
tran_amt0                         0
avg_amt_prod_3m                5006
avg_amt_vnebs_3m               1518
avg_amt_avto_3m               10479
avg_amt_inet_3m                9044
churn                             0
product_type                      0
top_cat                        1296
dtype: int64
```

Критично ли будет удалить строки или лучше заменить средним/медианой? Опасаюсь, что удаление почти половины значений, хоть и нулевых скажется потом на точности модели

Comment: строго говоря, Nan - это не нулевые значения.  я бы советовал использовать для замены pandas mean, тем более, что она по умолчанию не учитывает nan в подсчете.

Comment: Вообще все зависит от модели и от того, какие столбцы с данными имеют много пропусков, вообще можно заменить средним, но это может сказаться на точности модели, если данных в целом много, то можно отбросить все что с пропусками, главное чтоб оставшихся данных хватало для обучения, есть еще вариант,  используя метод ближайших соседей заполнить пропуски средним значением из строк, данные которых максимально похожи на на данные из строки с пропуском, но это не всегда работает корректно и тоже может понизить точность, в общем все зависит от конкретной ситуации, надо пробовать разные подходы)